# Client-based API - processing multiple JSONs

Tags: javascript, json, api

I want to build a special "API".

The API calls other **multiple APIs** (answer in JSON), picks single parts of the responses, **compose** it and print out to one single JSON.

I want to compose the different JSON by using a kind of **mapping**:
e.g. the old `data[0].event.title` is mapped to the new `data.title`

I already build a REST API on a Java Server with the Jersey Framework.

**My question:** Is it possible to build such an API with JavaScript or a client script language to *reduce the work load on the server*. The server only provides the code.

The client uses the code to "compose the json" as I mentioned above. At the end I want to make a HTTP Request e.g GET *https://apirulXXX.de/2/api/composedjson* and I want to get the client-processed JSON.

What framework can I use? What is possible?

Comment: Maybe [GraphQL](https://graphql.org/) or [Falcor](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/).

Comment: GraphQL is query language for my API. I want to build a API which is not hosted on a server. Falcor also need an application server. Is there a way to build a "client-only" composing API as I described it? @dNitro